# Get a NullPointerException on Parse Signup?

Tags: android, parse-platform, nullpointerexception

Here's my sign up method:

```
    public void signUp(View v) {
         String firstNameString = FirstName.getText().toString();
         String familyNameString = LastName.getText().toString();
         String emailString = email.getText().toString();
         String passwordString = password.getText().toString();

//        final String passwordConfirmString = passwordConfirm.getText().toString();
//    if( passwordConfirmString != passwordString){
//        Toast passwordsDoNotMatch = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Passwords do not match",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
//        passwordsDoNotMatch.show();
//    }

         ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
//        if (firstNameString.length() < 2 && firstNameString.isEmpty()) {
//            FNTooShort.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//        }
//        if (familyNameString.length()<2){
//            FANTooShort.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//        }
//        if (firstNameString ==null){
//            FNEmpty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//        }
//        if (familyNameString==null){
//            FANEmpty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//        }
//        if(passwordString==null){
//            PSempty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//        }
//        if(passwordString.length()<8){
//            PSempty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//        }
//        else {
            user.setUsername(firstNameString + familyNameString);
            user.setEmail(emailString);
            user.setPassword(passwordString);
            user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        CharSequence success = "Sign up Successfull";
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                        Toast successfullTostConformation = Toast.makeText(context, success, duration);
                        successfullTostConformation.show();
//                        String userIDString = user.getObjectId().toString();
//                        editor.putString("user_id", userIDString);
//                        editor.putString("username", firstNameString + " " + familyNameString);
//                        editor.putString("password", passwordString);
//                        editor.putString("email", emailString);
//                        editor.commit();
                        Intent startLogin = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                        SignUpActivity.this.startActivity(startLogin);

                    } else {
//                    There was an error making the user

                    }
                }
            });
//        }
    }
```

I've tried commenting out the if statements as you can see, but no good. I know the meaning of nullpoinerexception but I cant find where the error is.
It was working before I added some if statements, then the error happened. So I removed them and it's still not working!
Logcat:

```
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.alibdeir.signupactivity, PID: 3007
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:278)
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19270)
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:273)
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633) 
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19270) 
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.alibdeir.signupactivity.SignUpActivity.signUp(SignUpActivity.java:54)
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:273) 
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633) 
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19270) 
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
11-19 21:21:34.763 3007-3007/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you put the exception log?

Comment: mmm, And what is on line 54 of SignUpActivity.java?? 
("Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.alibdeir.signupactivity.SignUpActivity.signUp(SignUpActivity.java:54)")

Comment: @mayo Wow, unlike me, you are one excellent reader. I have deleted the email textbox in my layout and removed the definition in the oncreate, but kept EditText email; and I had String email = email.getText().toString()

Comment: cool ;) !!
Sometimes the exception log is overwhelming, but sometimes if you read line by line ( looking first for the 'Causes at'...) you will find the cause !